# ZeroClipboard - Error in Actionscript

Tags: jquery, flash, zeroclipboard

I'm using ZeroClipboard v2.2.0 from [cdnjs](http://cdnjs.com/libraries/zeroclipboard)

Running this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("tr td:last-child").each(function() {
        var element = $(this);
        var button = $('<button type="button" class="btn btn-xs copy-to-clipboard" data-clipboard-text="' + element.html() + '" title="Copy UUID"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-file"></span></button>');
        button.tooltip();

        button.appendTo(element);

        var clipboard = new ZeroClipboard(button);
        clipboard.on("ready", function(event) {
            clipboard.on("aftercopy", function(event) {
                alert("Copied: " +  event.data["text/plain"]);
            });
        });
    });
});
```

This code inserts the `copy to clipboard` buttons in the table:
[image: Table]

But when i drag over one of these `copy to clipboard` buttons, firebug shows this exception: `uncaught exception: Error in Actionscript. Use a try/catch block to find error.`

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it. Had to add some configuration:

```
ZeroClipboard.config({
        swfPath: '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/zeroclipboard/2.2.0/ZeroClipboard.swf',
        forceHandCursor: true,
        debug: true,
        trustedDomains: [window.location.host, "cdnjs.cloudflare.com"]
    });
```